# Language and Currency Switcher are not working on Magento 2.2.2 in Mac safari and Chrome Explorer

Tags: magento2, language

**Preconditions**

Magento2 ce 2.2.2
php 7.0.1
3.Mac safari 11.1 and Chrom67.0.3396.87 Explorer
**Steps to reproduce**
I had a Magento 2.2.2 with a website that has one store and two store's views (en and tc);

On Stores -> Configuration -> Web, I set "Add Store code to URLs" to "YES" OR "No"(I test)

in default store view(en), I change the language to Chinese, It works first time, Then I change the language to en， It works too；When I change the language to Chinese again, It doesn't work any more；Even if I refresh the page still does not work；

The issue seems to be related to caching, I clear the cache and switch languages, It works again;

**Expected result**

Language and currency Switcher can switch at any time;

**Actual result**

Language and currency Switcher are not working at the second time;

**ps:**
I test in phone7 safari and window Chrome, IE 9; It works any time;
The issue occurs in Mac Safari and Chrome Explorer;

Answer (score -1):

It works after we add the following setting;

> Magento Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Cookie
>   Setting